# Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method getSystemService(String) from the type Context

Tags: android

I am new to android. I have already given all the permissions. Please tell me how to instance TelephonyManager

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    TelephonyManager telephonyManager= (TelephonyManager) Context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    Class clazz = Class.forName(telephonyManager.getClass().getName());
    Method method = clazz.getDeclaredMethod("getITelephony");
    method.setAccessible(true);
    ITelephony telephonyService = (ITelephony) method.invoke(telephonyManager);
    telephonyService.endCall();

}
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: instance of TelephonyManager Class @DiegoTorresMilano

Answer (score 1):

As this message is telling you, `getSystemService()` is not a static method, and thus you need a `Context` instance to use that method.

Calling `Context.getSystemService()` attempts to access it statically.

If you are trying to do this in an Activity, you can simply call `getSystemService()` or `this.getSystemService()`, since an Activity is a Context.

if you are trying to do this in a Fragment, you can call `getContext().getSystemService()`.

Comment: i need to make an instance of TelephonyManager class. suggest

Comment: Your existing code will work if you make the one change I told you to make.